# Problema con importacion de modulos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Es una duda un poco novata, sin embargo no me quiero quedar con la incognita.
Tengo carpeta llamada entities, la cual quiero que sea un modulo, por lo que tiene su pertinente **init**.py, quedando la estructura de la siguiente forma.

```
entities
       | __init__.py
       | product.py
       | shopping_cart.py
```

En el archivo product.py tengo lo siguiente:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, discount: float = 0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.discount = discount
```

Y en el shopping_Cart tengo

```
from entities.product import Product

    class ShoppingCart:
        
        def __init__(self):
            self.__product = []
               
        
        def add_product(self, product):
            
            if product.__class__.__name__ == 'Product':
                self.__product.append(product)
            else:
                print('No es producto')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cart = ShoppingCart()
    product = Product('Apple', 500.00)
    
    cart.add_product(product)
```

si hago pruebas desde el main.py todo bien, pero si quiero ejecutar las pruebas directamente en shopping_cart.py, en la seccion de `if __name__ == '__main__':` me da el siguiente error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\entities\shopping_cart.py", line 1, in <module>
    from entities.product import Product
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'entities'
```

Como puedo correr el codigo directamente en el shopping_cart y que me detecte los demas archivos

Comment: ¿Cómo estás ejecutando shopping_cart? Me refiero al comando que utilizas.

Comment: py shopping_cart.py 
y tambien intente 
py -m shopping_cart.py

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar algún archivo que es parte de un módulo debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
python -m entities.shopping_cart
```

Es importante que corras el comando sin utilizar el `.py` y que sea ejecutado desde la carpeta raíz del proyecto. Por lo tanto primero debes hacer `cd carpeta raíz` y desde ahí ejecutar el comando que te mencione anteriormente.

```
/carpeta-raiz
├── entities
│   ├── Product.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── shopping_cart.py
└── main.py
```

Sin embargo, quizás al hacer esto también debes cambiar la forma de importar `Product` en `shopping_cart.py`.

Tendrás que cambiar este import:

```
from entities.product import Product
```

a la siguiente forma:

```
from .product import Product
```

Comment: Al hacer el cambio que propones da el siguiente resultado:

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: ¿Estas corriendo el comando que mencione en la carpeta `root` de tu proyecto? Haz intentado quitar el `.` antes de `product`?

Comment: Por tu comentario arriba creo que estás corriendo mal las cosas. Debes dejar el import como te mencioné. Y debes correr sin ningun `.py`. Para correrlo debes estar en el mismo nivel que la carpeta `entities`, mas no dentro de la carpeta entities. Recuerda, debes hacer `python -m entities.shopping_cart` sin el .py del final.

Comment: Ahora que ejecuto el modulo como mencionas me sale lo siguiente: ``` RuntimeWarning: 'entities.shopping_cart' found in sys.modules after import of package 'entities', but prior to execution of 'entities.shopping_cart'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg)) ```

Comment: ¿Como tienes el import de `product`? Tienes algo en tu `__init__.py`?

Answer (score -1):

No lo pusiste, pero imagino que el `main.py` esta fuera de `entities/`, es decir al mismo nivel.

Entonces, si vos ejecutas desde `main.py`, obviamente existe el modulo "entities" pero si vos ejecutas desde `shopping_cart.py` que esta dentro de la carpeta `entities/`, ya no va a encontrar el modulo ahi adentro.

Se entiende? Siempre va a ser relativo a tu punto de entrada.

Comment: La pregunta habla de ejecutar el `shopping_cart` de forma independiente a un archivo `main` que importe dicho archivo. Es decir, ejecutar directamente lo que se encuentra bajo `if __name__ == '__main__':` en el archivo `shopping_cart.py`

Comment: En efecto, el codigo funciona correctamente desde el main.py, pero quisiera poder hacer pruebas directamente en shopping_cart.py, esto para tener mas ordenado el codigo